# Clarification with logarithms $n^{\log\log n} = (\log n)^{\log n}$.

Tags: algorithms, logarithms

How come the following are all true?:

$n^{\log_2\log_2 n} = (\log_2 n)^{\log_2 n}$

$n^2 = 4^{\log_2 n}$

$n = 2^{\log_2 n}$

$2^{\sqrt {2\log_2 n}} = n^{\sqrt {2/\log_2 n}}$

$1 = n ^ {1/ \log_2 n}$

Comment: By $lgn$ do you mean $\log n$?

Comment: @mrnovice Most likely $\operatorname{lg}=\log_2$.

Comment: @mrnovice exactly what GSassatelli said

Comment: This seems like a homework. Say what you tried and we can help you.

Comment: The trick is always the same. You have the claim $$x^{\text{something}}\stackrel{?}= y^{\text{SsSsomething}}$$ and you want to verify it. How can you do it? Well, you use the astounding, *unheard*, **unconceavable** identities $$a=2^{\log_2a}\\ (a^b)^c=a^{bc}$$ and check whether $$2^{(\log_2x)\cdot \text{something}}\stackrel?=2^{(\log_2y)\cdot \text{SsSsomething}}$$ by equating the exponents-

Comment: @DanusoRocha it's not a homework, ive been preparing for my test and was going over the relevant stuff. The above identities are put as `Some facts: ....`, but im not sure how these identities are equal

Comment: $n = 2^{\log_2 n}$ is almost an  identity. $\log_2 n$ is the number you raise two to to get $n$, so when you raise two to $\log_2 n$ you get $n$. So simple it's difficult. :D

Comment: In high school I always thought it was the coolest thing that $x^{1/\log x} =e$, that you can raise a nonconstant function to a nonconstant power and get a constant.

Comment: $1 = n ^ {1/ \log_2 n}$ is wrong, no?

If $n=2$,  $1 \ne 2 ^ {1/ \log_2 2}=2 ^ {1/1}=2$

Comment: $n^{\log_2\log_2 n} = (\log_2 n)^{\log_2 n}$,

Try $n=4$,

$2^{\log_2\log_2 4} = 2^{\log_2 2} = 2 \ne 2^2 = (\log_2 4)^{\log_2 4}$. I wonder if the edit changed the supposed identities.

Comment: @Arby $4^{\log_2 \log_2 4} = 4^{\log_2 2} = 4 = 2^2 = (\log_2 4)^{\log_2 4}$. So it's correct.

Comment: oops, you're right! Too many twos! 8-)

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$x=n^{\log_2(\log_2 n)}$$
Taking $\log_2$ on both sides,
$$\begin{array}{rcl} \log_2 x &=& \log_2\left[n^{\log_2(\log_2 n)}\right] \\ &=& \log_2(\log_2 n)\cdot\log_2 n \\ &=& \log_2\left[\left(\log_2 n\right)^{\log_2 n}\right] \end{array}$$
Therefore
$$x=\left(\log_2 n\right)^{\log_2 n}$$
This answers your first question. Your other questions except the last one are basically arithmetic; for example $n=2^{\log_2n}$ is just saying that $\log_2n=\log_2n$. Your last statement however appears not to be true; I think you mean
$$2=n^{1/\log_2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think..The main identity in your problems..

$$a^{\log_bc}=c^{\log_ba}$$
S0 $1),2),3)$ are true...$4),5)$ is false try $n=1$ ..Moreover ,even if it was defined

$$n^{1/\log_2n}=n^{\log_n2}=2\neq1$$

EDIT:

The identity itself can be proved easily

$$\log_ac=\frac{\log_bc}{\log_ba}$$

$$\log_ac\cdot\log_ba=\log_bc\cdot\log_aa$$
$$\log_ac^{\log_ba}=\log_aa^{\log_bc}$$
$$c^{\log_ba}=a^{\log_bc}$$